# Java Concurrency in Practice: race condition in BoundedExecutor?

Tags: java, concurrency, race-condition, executor

There's something odd about the implementation of the `BoundedExecutor` in the book Java Concurrency in Practice.

It's supposed to throttle task submission to the Executor by blocking the submitting thread when there are enough threads either queued or running in the Executor.

This is the implementation (after adding the missing rethrow in the catch clause):

```
public class BoundedExecutor {
    private final Executor exec;
    private final Semaphore semaphore;

    public BoundedExecutor(Executor exec, int bound) {
        this.exec = exec;
        this.semaphore = new Semaphore(bound);
    }

    public void submitTask(final Runnable command) throws InterruptedException, RejectedExecutionException {
        semaphore.acquire();

        try {
            exec.execute(new Runnable() {
                @Override public void run() {
                    try {
                        command.run();
                    } finally {
                        semaphore.release();
                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (RejectedExecutionException e) {
            semaphore.release();
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

When I instantiate the `BoundedExecutor` with an `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()` and a bound of 4, I would expect the number of threads instantiated by the cached thread pool to never exceed 4. In practice, however, it does. I've gotten this little test program to create as much as 11 threads:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    class CountingThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory {
        int count;

        @Override public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
            ++count;
            return new Thread(r);
        }           
    }

    List<Integer> counts = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int n = 0; n < 100; ++n) {
        CountingThreadFactory countingThreadFactory = new CountingThreadFactory();
        ExecutorService exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(countingThreadFactory);

        try {
            BoundedExecutor be = new BoundedExecutor(exec, 4);

            for (int i = 0; i < 20000; ++i) {
                be.submitTask(new Runnable() {
                    @Override public void run() {}
                });
            }
        } finally {
            exec.shutdown();
        }

        counts.add(countingThreadFactory.count);
    }

    System.out.println(Collections.max(counts));
}
```

I think there's a tiny little time frame between the release of the semaphore and the task ending, where another thread can aquire a permit and submit a task while the releasing thread hasn't finished yet. In other words, it has a race condition.

Can someone confirm this?

Comment: I added a 1ms Thread.sleep just after the semaphore.release() to see how much worse it would get: I got over 300 threads created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see as much as 9 threads created at once.  I suspect there is a race condition which causes there to be more thread than required.

This could be because there is before and after running the task work to be done.  This means that even though there is only 4 thread inside your block of code, there is a number of thread stopping a previous task or getting ready to start a new task.

i.e. the thread does a release() while it is still running. Even though its the last thing you do its not the last thing it does before acquiring a new task.

Comment: I agree with your statement, which is also basically what Bossie suspected in the first place.  But I'm not sure I would call this a race condition since it implies some programming error: I don't think the program is supposed to have a maximum number of threads as it is written.

Comment: @toto2 Its not a regular programming bug, but there is a race condition between the Semaphore being released and the thread acquiring a new task. If the task where longer lived you might only see this behaviour rarely.

Comment: I understand about the task length (see my comment to Bossie's question).  I just mean it's not a bug because there is nothing specifying that there should be 4 threads. "It's not a bug, it's a feature!"  In this case I think someone could really make that claim.  Sorry... I'm just getting philosophical here.

Comment: I don't think it's a bug, but if someone wanted to fix it, I don't see any way (except of course to have a 4-thread executor).

Comment: @toto2: my point is that the BoundedExecutor is supposed to help prevent an excess of memory used/threads created but in extremely rare conditions it just doesn't. It never leads to illegal program state in the way that a typical race condition does but it isn't 100% reliable either. Won't stop me from using it in my programs though.

Comment: @Bossie Personally, I would just use a fixed size thread pool. It seems simpler to me.

Answer (score 10):

BoundedExecutor was indeed intended as an illustration of how to throttle task submission, not as a way to place a bound on thread pool size. There are more direct ways to achieve the latter, as at least one comment pointed out.

But the other answers don't mention the text in the book that says to use an unbounded queue and to

> set the bound on the semaphore to be equal to the pool size *plus* the
>   number of queued tasks you want to allow, since the semaphore is
>   bounding the number of tasks both currently executing and awaiting
>   execution. *[JCiP, end of section 8.3.3]*

By mentioning unbounded queues and pool size, we were implying (apparently not very clearly) the use of a thread pool of bounded size.

What has always bothered me about BoundedExecutor, however, is that it doesn't implement the ExecutorService interface. A modern way to achieve similar functionality and still implement the standard interfaces would be to use Guava's [listeningDecorator](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v12.0/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/MoreExecutors.html#listeningDecorator%28java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService%29) method and [ForwardingListeningExecutorService](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v12.0/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/ForwardingListeningExecutorService.html) class.

Comment: An answer from one of the experts, that's awesome. Thanks for making things a little clearer Tim. Those `ListenableFuture`s do look interesting. So I'm supposed to submit a couple of tasks, and whenever one completes, I submit a new one in the callback, right?

Comment: @Bossie - You could do that, sure, but I meant that you could continue to use the Semaphore approach of BoundedExecutorService by decorating the execute with an acquire and the callback with a release.

Answer (score 5):

You are correct in your analysis of the race condition.  There is no synchronization guarantees between the ExecutorService & the Semaphore.

However, I do not know if throttling the number of threads is what the BoundedExecutor is used for.  I think it is more for throttling the number of tasks submitted to the service.  Imagine if you have 5 million tasks that need to submit, and if you submit more then 10,000 of them you run out of memory.

Well you only will ever have 4 threads running at any given time, why would you want to try and queue up all 5 millions tasks?  You can use a construct similar to this to throttle the number of tasks queued up at any given time.  What you should get out of this is that at any given time there are only 4 tasks running.

Obviously the resolution to this is to use a `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4)`.

Comment: Exactly. The task submitted to the underlying executor that runs `command` releases the semaphore before it completes, but this happens in the executor thread running the task. This allows another task to be submitted to the executor and given to a new thread, theoretically allowing twice as many threads as `bound` given the right conditions.

Comment: @John: it does throttle the number of tasks submitted, but in an unpredictable and unreliable way. If threads are scheduled in an unfortunate manner, this could mean that a lot of submitting threads could sneak in. Also, in the case of a `newFixedThreadPool()`, these tasks can still pile up in the `Executor`'s unbounded queue, still risking out-of-memory . @David: I've gotten as much as 11 threads with a bound of 4. Also, I think it's funny that the reference book on Java concurrency still has race conditions in it.

Comment: @Bossie You are right, you are still suspect to OOM with a newFixedThreadPool but that would prevent the excess threads created.  You use a bound to prevent, as I mentioned, the millions of tasks being submitted at one time.

Comment: @Bossie - You're right, if many threads yield after releasing the lock and stagnate, you can get many more threads piling up.